# Is there a way to filter and find a defaulted interface?

Tags: cisco-commands

If I run the command **sh ip int bri | inc down**, I can filter to see which ports are down or admin down. Some interfaces may still have configuration on them but I am curious to know if there is a way to see which ports are defaulted without having to do a **sh run** for each interface?

For example is there a way I can filter which interfaces have this default configuration?

```
Switch#sh run int GigabitEthernet1/1 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 61 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
no ip address
shutdown
end
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to filter on information that is _not_ in the interface? You can only filter on what is there, not what is not there.

Comment: just show run and eyeball it.  The `show ip int br` gives you a quick summary of all the int status.  I guess that's not what you're looking for but ... i dunno.  Each line can be defaulted by saying, e.g., default ip address, default description, as far as I remember.   Certainly wr erase gets you back to default the quickest.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> For example is there a way I can filter which interfaces have this default configuration?

Found a rather different solution for this, you need to have **pcregrep** installed on linux server from where you are doing ssh to the router, Run the following command:

```
 ssh "Username"@"IP of the router" "sh run" | pcregrep -M  'interface.*\n.*no ip address.*\n.*shutdown.*\n.*!'
```

This would work with **default interface** configuration provided by you i.e.

> ```
> Switch#sh run int GigabitEthernet1/1 
> Building configuration...
>
> Current configuration : 61 bytes
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet1/1
> no ip address
> shutdown
> end
> ```

Any other configuration(if different from this) of default configuration like variations in IOS-XR, IOS-XE or a Switch can be put in instead of the current lines.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can have interfaces which were not defaulted that have no IP address on them. There could be a lot of other configurations on the interface. For example, an interface which has subinterfaces for a trunk will have the IP addresses on the subinterfaces, but the physical interface will not. Such an interface has not been defaulted.

Comment: Please read the solution, again I have taken that into account from interface name till end of the interface configuration. "an interface which has subinterfaces for a trunk will have the IP addresses on the subinterfaces" -- will not have shutdown on trunk interface.

Comment: I still don't believe you have taken into account everything. For instance, why do you have "end" in there. That is not something that shows up in an interface configuration. There can be other configurations in an interface which has `no ip address` and `shutdown`. Those interfaces have not been defaulted.

Comment: I just looked at a router that had the IP address removed and the interface shut, but it starts off just like what the OP has, but it has a lot of other configuration after the `shutdown`. The interface was never defaulted.

Comment: **edited: removed end and added "!" instead** , Any more cases are welcome. Editions are always welcome :). In the end we have to provide a solution and that is important.

Comment: What you need to do is besides the two lines is to discover that there is nothing else in the interface configuration. That could be easy for interfaces which are followed by other interfaces, but not for the last interface in a list because it could be followed by anything, but still be defaulted.

Comment: Well still this solution can work for **any number of common continuous lines** you want to take out from a running configuration, The current solution is framed according to question asked i.e. the configuration of default configuration given by **questioner**. **Adding this to the solution**. Also I see the "!" Sign after every section of running configuration, So I am not sure about "but not for the last interface in a list because it could be followed by anything". Thanks :)

Comment: There are some interface configurations which have and exclamation point in them. I run into that every once in a while. They _usually_ all have it after the configuration for the interface, but _some_ also have it in the configuration.

Comment: The current edited solution takes your concern into account, "There are some interface configurations which have and exclamation point in them." -- Hmm, Yes in case of tunnels et al. But then the current edited solution should be ok for this case(I guess).